# Talking from mobile to angular app that is communicating with the c# server via localhost

Tags: c#, angular, networking

I have an angular client run on my laptop under Tomcat web server. I am accessing client from my mobile phone through my router public address (I have set the the NAT to forward all TCP packets to web server on my laptop). My client communicates with the c# controller using `http://localhost:4000`. Whenever I try to send a request from my mobile I get `Unknown Error` message. Could the problem be caused by the fact that I am using public address from my mobile, but the client is using localhost to communicate to c# controller?

Comment: The local host has to be on the internet and have a public IP.  Also all IP should be either IPV4 or IPV6.  The IP address[] is an array where index 0 is usually V6 and index 1 is V4.

Comment: The router has public address - but I set router to forward all TCP packets to my laptop - is that enough or I need to do something else?

Comment: The Angular client is hosted by the web server, but is downloaded and executed on the browser - in the context of the mobile. So for mobile, `localhost` is the phone itself, so it does not know where to find the API. You need to access the API also using the public IP address and port 4000. If all requests are routed to your laptop, this might be enough (if the firewall on the laptop does allow accessing port 4000 from other sources). From a security point of view, I'd work toward a solution that directs only certain requests (e.g. HTTP/HTTPS) to the laptop.

Comment: Markus. Thanks for the reply. I have a problem because my c# server listening on port `localhost:4000` is not a web server- how do I forward those requests from mobile to the c# server that is listening on `localhost:4000`. Any help very appreciated

Comment: Can I treat c# server as a web server?

Comment: If you forward all requests to the server (that is a setting on the router), then the port should not be a problem. The client however, should not try to reach http://localhost:4000 when accessing the API, but http://<public ip>:4000. Still, the firewall on the laptop could block requests to port 4000. You can try to send a `GET` request to the API from the mobile using the public IP and port 4000. If this works, Angular should also be able to reach the port on your laptop.

Comment: I have created two entries in NAT one for port 8080 and one for 4000 to forward TCP packet to the service type `Web Server` - is that enough? I can't specify the range 4000-8080 because router complained about some port in between that is used for management

Comment: Yes, that should do. Mind the firewall on the laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248318/discussion-between-user19564787-and-markus).